# No config files after a PostgreSQL installation on Debian Stretch

Tags: postgresql, debian

I had installed postgresql and postgis on new Debian stable (Stretch 9) like I did it on Debian 8.

When I'm connecting as postgresql user, I had an error:

```
postgres@servername:~$ psql
```

> psql: n'a pas pu se connecter au serveur : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
>          Le serveur est-il actif localement et accepte-t-il les connexions sur la
>          socket Unix « /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 » ?

Translation:

> psql: cannot connect to server: No file or directory of this kind. Is the server locally activated and does it accept connection on Unix Socket « /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 » ?

So, I would like to have a look on my config file, but `/etc/postgresql` directory is empty ! There is no pg_hba.conf and no postgresql.conf !

```
root@servername:/etc# locate pg_hba.conf
/usr/share/postgresql/9.6/pg_hba.conf.sample
```

What did I wrong when installing postgresql?

Here is the command that I have launch to install it:

```
# apt-get install apache2 php phppgadmin postgresql postgresql-client postgis
```

The service seems to be running:

```
root@servername:/etc# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-07-04 07:13:05 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 6982 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6982 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

juil. 04 07:13:05 cthedifference systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
juil. 04 07:13:05 cthedifference systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

But I find no running process:

```
# ps -edf|grep postgres
root      7077   908  0 07:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep postgres
```

Log directory `/var/log/postgresql/` is empty.

Comment: try as su `find / -name pg_hba.conf` instead of locate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly [install](https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#Installation) and [configure](https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#User_access) `postgresql` follow the instructions of the official documentation debian:

```
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
```

The configuration files should be found under `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main`:

```
# ls /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
```

Sample output:

```
environment  pg_hba.conf    postgresql.conf
pg_ctl.conf  pg_ident.conf  start.conf
```

Comment: It was exactly what I have done. But the directory was empty. I purged postgresql packet and I reinstalled them by using:
`apt-get purge postgresql* &&
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client` and it worked. I didn't understand why the directory was empty. I thought a disconnection or a problem append and stop installation. I don't know. But now it works.

Comment: Same issue for me. I run `apt-get install postgresql-13` and no folder like `/etc/postgresql/13`. I have two new packages installed and named `postgresql-13`, `postgresl-client-13` but when I run `sudo -u postgres pg_lsclusters` there isn't the 13 cluster. I also try `apt-get install --reinstall postgresql-common` to update files but nothing better. Finally I removed and installed `postgresql-13` `postgresql-client-13` and `postgresql-13-postgis-3` again. At the end of the installation I had: `Success You can now run the database server with pg_ctlclusters 13 main start` and files where here.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, its installed service is running! but /etc/postgresql is empty.